# Can a YAML file imported into an API spec reference another include YAML file?

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Using swagger-editor and swagger-ui to build a swagger2.0 specification in YAML.

I have split the spec into a client.yml and several model.yml files.

Each model defines some parameters or response objects.

When I open client.yml in the editor, it will load the models into the client using $ref:

However, there appears to be a problem if an object in one of the model files tries to reference an object in another model file.

I have tried absolute and relative paths to no avail. I always get an error, like:
"Reference could not be resolved: /models/basemodel.yml#/BasicObject"
 path: Array [10]

```
error: "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'BasicObject' in undefined"
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description: "Reference could not be resolved: /models/basemodel.yml#/BasicObject"
lineNumber: -1
```

The SimplerObject is identical and works fine. This references a CopyOfBasicObject in the same file. The AdvancedObject tries to reference the BasicObject in a different model file.

The goal is to not copy the definition of BasicObject but refer to it.

It is often necessary to clear the browser cache and reload the page before the editor read the new version of the model file.

The files I used to test this are included. I have converted to a single file as stackoverflow editor is not rendering the yaml very well.

```
    swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: test indirect reference
  description: etc
  version: "Draft 0.1.1"
host: example.com
basePath: /
produces:
  - application/json

paths:
  /advancedObjects:

     post:
      summary: |
        post an object.
      parameters:
        - name: advancedObject
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '/models/model.yml#/AdvancedObject' # This doeesn't work
              #$ref: '/models/model.yml#/SimplerObject' # This works fine
              #$ref: '/models/basemodel.yml#/BasicObject'  # This works fine
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
    definitions: 

       AdvancedObject:  #move to /models/model.yml
          type: object
          description: Contains a reference to a basic object
          properties:
            base:
              $ref: '/models/basemodel.yml#/BasicObject'
            advanced:
              type: array
              items:
                type: number


      CopyOfBasicObject: # move to /models/model.yml
        type: object
        description: Another simple object
        properties:
          id:
            type: number

      SimplerObject: # move to /models/model.yml
        type: object
        description: Same as AdvanceObject but without reference to another file
        properties:
          base:
            $ref: '#/CopyOfBasicObject'
          advanced:
            type: array
            items:
              type: number

      BasicObject: # move to /models/basemodel.yml
        type: object
        description: A simple object
        properties:
          id:
            type: number
```